# Is there 'this' linakge pointer in PHP

Tags: php, shorthand

I was wondering, if it's possible not to repeat your self when using *if* statements in PHP. The following is the part of my `spl_autoload_register` function, e.g.:

```
if (is_file(Core::Config('plugins_path') . '/' . strtolower($required_class) . '.class.php'))
  {
      require_once (Core::Config('plugins_path') . '/' . strtolower($required_class) . '.class.php');
  }
```

Is there a way to write it familiar to:

```
if (is_file(Core::Config('plugins_path') . '/' . strtolower($required_class) . '.class.php'))
  {
      require_once ( this );
  }
```

in order not to duplicate exactly the same line of the code?

The example above is not working.. Is there a way really?

Comment: No, just store the string to a variable and use it in both places.

Comment: @Michael, Thank you! Well, sad a bit, that's what I thought though really!

Comment: That isn't remotely what `this` means.

Comment: @meagar I supposed that! :) But it would be great and perfectly logical! I was thinking that I could be missing something!

Comment: No, no language does this. You need to assign the result of your complex code in a variable, as the below answer indicates.

Comment: @meagar, In jQuery when using `$('#id')` as part of a function, it's possible! Why not register `if` statement into `this`?

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev That's completely different. You're invoking a function on an object, which is exactly when `this` makes sense: It's the object on which the function is being invoked. As for why you wouldn't do it, the answer is, there's no good reason to. The accepted answer below is how this is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly as you described. But you can shrink the code with a variable.

```
$file = Core::Config('plugins_path') . '/' . strtolower($required_class) . '.class.php';
if (is_file($file))
  {
      require_once ( $file );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the idea offered by [Pietu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1938435/pietu1998), I'd rather shorten it to:

```
$file = Core::Config('plugins_path') . '/' . strtolower( $required_class ) . '.class.php';
is_file( $file ) && require_once ( $file );
```